# String split by character

Tags: regex, r, string, split

I have 50 strings of this form:

```
 28 North Dakota 0 2 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 _1 _2 _1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 2 16 F 9.5610957 11
```

I want to separate the string after the state name. (Split the string at the last character) But there is character 'F' near the end of the string. So I split the string in half using this:

```
substring(x,1,nchar(x)/2)
```

Now I am left with this:

```
28 North Dakota 0 2 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 _1 _2 _1
```

Now I can try and separate the string after the last letter in the string. How do I do that? I understand that what I am doing is bad coding practice (Choosing to split the string in half).  Is there a smarter way of doing this?

I have a list of all the states. Could I use that as a dictionary to split the strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `str_split` with `n` option.  The lookaround regex implies we are splitting by one or more space that precedes a numeric value and succeeds a character.  As we specify the 'n' option as 2, it will split at the first instance of finding this pattern to give two splits.

```
library(stringr)
str_split(str1, "(?<=[a-z])\\s+(?=[0-9])", n = 2)[[1]]
#[1] "28 North Dakota"                                             
#[2] "0 2 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 _1 _2 _1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 2 16 F 9.5610957 11"
```

Or instead of using a package solution, we can also do with `strsplit` after creating a delimiter

```
strsplit(sub("(.*[a-z])\\s(.*)", "\\1,\\2", str1), ",")[[1]]
[1] "28 North Dakota"            
[2] "0 2 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 _1 _2 _1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 2 16 F 9.5610957 11"
```

---

If we need the first part alone.  We match one or more space (`\\s+`) followed by a digit (`\\d`) followed by characters to the end of the string (`.*`) and replace by `''`.

```
sub("\\s+\\d.*", "", str1)
#[1] "28 North Dakota"
```

If we need the state alone

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(str1, "[A-Za-z]+\\s*[A-Za-z]+")
#[1] "North Dakota"
```

NOTE: The OP mentioned about splitting after the state name.

#### data

```
 str1 <- "28 North Dakota 0 2 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 _1 _2 _1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 2 16 F 9.5610957 11"
```

Comment: Thanks for the base R option!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method using `gsub`:

```
gsub("^\\d+ ([A-Za-z ]+) \\d+.*", "\\1", temp)
"North Dakota"
```

The regular expression at the beginning says match a digit as the first character "^\d", maybe more than one digit "+", followed by a space " ". Then capture "()" the next set of alphabetical characters "[A-Za-z ]+" as well as spaces. Then match a space followed by at least one digit " \d+" and anything that follows ".*", the "\1" returns the captured subexpression.

To return the final part of the substring, you could move the capturing parentheses to the corresponding part of the regular expression.

```
gsub("^\\d+ [A-Za-z ]+ (\\d+.*)", "\\1", temp)
[1] "0 2 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 _1 _2 _1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 2 16 F 9.5610957 11"
```

or to capture the state name and the number that precedes it,

```
gsub("^(\\d+ [A-Za-z ]+) \\d+.*", "\\1", temp)
[1] "28 North Dakota
```

the example string:

```
temp <- c("28 North Dakota 0 2 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 _1 _2 _1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 2 16 F 9.5610957 11")
```